# Yii2 скачать файл после ajax-запроса

Tags: ajax, yii2

В Yii2 чтобы отдать клиенту файл на скачивание, есть метод

```
\Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);
```

Я во вьюшке сделал кнопку, при нажатии на которую:

1. Отправляется ajax-запрос с данными
2. На бэкэнде формируется файл исходя из принятых данных
3. Отдаю `\Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);`

Но т.к. это ajax-запрос, то файл формируется, но в браузере не скачивается.

Как с бэкенда можно дать команду браузеру скачать файл?

Comment: Как вариант - вместо самого файла можете скриптом отдать его URL, а уже на клиенте его получить и присвоить значением  document.location.href.

Comment: не получится. По прямой ссылке опасно отдавать, надо проверять права

Comment: Тогда можно отдавать ссылку не на сам файл, а на скрипт который его отдаст - заодно и права проверит

Comment: возможно, поможет SPA